# Postgres 9.5 import to MSSQL Server 2012 r2 verification issue

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table with 8 million rows. I need to copy it over to MSSQL. I do not have access to the console so I am unable to use PG_Dump. I have the ODBC driver, and have successfully linked up the servers. I was then able to copy the table over month by month. This was slow and painstaking. I need to create a query in postgresql that will list the year, month and total rows per month. The date field was actually created as text. I have tried this but do not get the results I am looking for.

```
SELECT distinct 
        date_part('Year',case 
        WHEN left(trandate,4) = '2014' then to_date(trandate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        else
        to_date(trandate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        end) as Year
    ,date_part('Month',case 
        WHEN left(trandate,4) = '2014' then to_date(trandate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        else
        to_date(trandate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        end)
         as month
    ,count(date_part('year',case 
        WHEN left(trandate,4) = '2014' then to_date(trandate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        else
        to_date(trandate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        end)) as "trandate sum"--date_part('Day',case 
    --  WHEN left(trandate,4) = '2014' then to_date(trandate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    --  else
    --  to_date(trandate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    --  end))
  FROM SomeSchema.transaction_detail

  Group By trandate
  order by date_part('Year',case 
        WHEN left(trandate,4) = '2014' then to_date(trandate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        else
        to_date(trandate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        end)
        ,date_trunc('Mon'  date_part('Month',case 
        WHEN left(trandate,4) = '2014' then to_date(trandate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        else
        to_date(trandate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        end))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please use the editing tools provided to make your posts more legible.

Comment: There is no 2012 R2 version of SQL Server. There are 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2014, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

This is more readable and may perform better:

```
SELECT date_part('year', month) as year,
       date_part('month', month) as month,
       count(*) as "trandate sum"
FROM (
  SELECT date_trunc('month', to_date(trandate, CASE
             WHEN left(trandate, 4) = '2014' THEN 'YYYY-MM-DD' ELSE 'MM/DD/YYYY' END
                    ))::date as month
  FROM SomeSchema.transaction_detail
  ) td
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Note that you could install PgAdminIII in your windows desktop, and use its pg_dump (in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin`), or start the console from PgAdmin (menu Plugins/PSQL Console). Depending on the type of data you're trying to import, a CSV format export file could be a good alternative. Otherwise, an SQL file via pg_dump with individual INSERT statements and processed via MSSQL's osql.exe or sqlcmd.exe tools to run it.